# Why can't we access the contents of a iFrame that is on another domain from a WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I mean accessing it from .NET code, not javascript. Is this just a negative vestige from javascript's security restrictions or is this something that is there for a real reason? I frankly can't find any.

I mean you can probably erase the guy's hard drive from code, but you can't access the contents of an iFrame...

Comment: Are you talking about the WinForms WebBorwser control?

Comment: @SLaks I see you just added a few tags to my question and thanks for that but, I'm not sure if C# should be there. Doesn't this apply to every other .NET language as well?

Comment: Correct; I added that tag to make it clear that you aren't talking about Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this limitation is connected to Internet Explorer's XSS (Cross Site Scripting) security.  I suggest briefly turning off XSS protection in IE's security settings and having another go.  If I remember correctly, the security settings for the winform browser are taken from the default version of IE, so changes in IE security apply to your form.  In IE 8 you can turn off XSS protection through "Internet Options->Security->Custom Level" and checking the disable radio button for "Enable XSS Filter".